# Telerik MVC Grid - Client Side Object Model for Databinding Urls

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, telerik-mvc

Are the data binding Urls encapsulated in the Telerik MVC Grid Client Side object?

Scenario is;
I'm tapping in to a onSave client side event for some validations. After validations are passed I need to post to Insert Databinding Url conditionally based on user confirmation.

NOTE : I can't use javascript confirm to hold the thread as I'm using jQuery UI dialog for confirmation

Comment: What do you mean by "encapsulated" - "exposed"?

Comment: Yes Atanas..what I meant is whether it's exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert url is exposed as `ajax.insertUrl`:

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");
var insertUrl = grid.ajax.insertUrl;
```